# Any way to make AirPort Express speaker available as just a speaker so I can stream the sound from a movie as well?

Tags: wireless-networking, speakers, airport-express

This might sound crazy, but I wanted to ask anyway.
The idea of having to play mp3s through iTunes only is crazy (too closed).
Yes, Linux has another player which can go through AirPort Express.
But, I want to be able to use any player that produces sound over AirPort Express.
Is this too far fetched? Even though I ask this basic question, I do work in IT myself.
The idea that Steve Jobs should decide what I can and cannot use angers me.
Is there any way to do this?

I am interested in doing this for Mac first, then for Ubuntu, then under Windows 7 if possible.

I looked at this, and it does not seem to be the silver bullet.

http://raop-play.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

There's a software product called [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) which lets you do just that. Haven't tried it with Windows but I use it daily with OS X to play audio from Spotify to several Airport Expresses, and it pretty much just works.

Comment: Are you using the free version? Does it work for you?

Comment: If you need other apps (besides iTunes) to be able to send a buffer-delayed audio stream to an AirPort Express, than Airfoil is a fine solution. It's not a solution for a locally-played video with remotely-played audio, because of the sync problem. The sync problem is also a problem for gaming or for using it as your general-purpose system sound output device, because game sounds and warning beeps and other UI event sounds would play a second too late.

Comment: Rogue Amoeba (Airfoil's maker) offer an Airfoil-compatible video player, here: http://www.rogueamoeba.com/support/knowledgebase/?showArticle=AirfoilVideoPlayer that claims to solve the sync issue.  I haven't tried the video player myself but I do use Airfoil for remoting my music.

Answer (score 0):

#### You don't want this. Your audio would always be off by a second or two from your video.

Currently, AirTunes audio is buffered, not realtime. There's no coordination protocol to keep your locally-displayed, realtime movie frames in sync with your remotely-output, buffer-delayed audio stream.

Air**Play** will allow both audio *and* video to be streamed together, just like Air**Tunes** does for audio-only today. I'm not sure if it will provide a way for you to do local video playback in sync with remote audio playback, but if it does, I think it'll solve what you're looking for. However, it still won't solve the "I want my game sounds and system UI sounds to be output remotely" scenario that some people want.

Answer (score 0):

^ you can also adjust a/v synching in VLC.  So if you play it locally in VLC, if fairly certain you can adjust in milliseconds and make it work.

Comment: Please elaborate.